# As per JPA spec, default constructor is must in entity classes, why?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, specifications

I have a question, As I have mentioned above, I know as per JPA spec and Hibernate doc, the default constructor is must and should have package level access. I would like to know that without the public constructor it the code still works. Why?

I also got into the code of Class.java I found a line as below

```
// No cached value available; request value from VM
```

Does this means that it requests a constructor from VM? i.e. the default constructor. Does this mean that my code(without default constructor) is VM dependent? What about byte code enhancement?

My Refactored Question:

I want to know why JPA has added this a "MUST" requirement to define a default constructor for an entity.

As per the spec:

```
The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may have other constructors as well.
The no-arg constructor must be public or protected.
```

Why so? I know that Java does introduces a default constructor if one is not defined, then why to put this in spec?

I hope I have placed my question correctly this time.

Thanks Again... :)

Comment: why not start by posting your class? If you don't have a constructor then the compiler gives you one for free. Other JPA impls can add a default ctr using bytecode enhancement so you don't need to define one there either.

Comment: I know this please read my question, you have answered only 1 thing which I already know. What I want to know is what is the purpose of making it compulsory in JPA spec?? Why the spec has to define this.

Comment: And to the down voter, please this site is not only for those guys who have their reputations in thousands, I am curious about this I tried "GOOGLING" but couldn't find any satisfactory answer, thats why posting here. If you can't answer doesn't mean the question is bad or naive

Comment: Unless you post the class (or better a decompiled form of your compiled class we can't see what it actually has in it, whether a default constructor has been added in the compilation/enhancement process) people can't comment further (and we don't know what you already know). Ranting on at whoever downvoted your question ain't going to help anything, and better still to focus on providing more info where others have asked for it. Why is it in the JPA spec ? ask the people who wrote it, but I'd expect it to be to instantiate an object, being the reliable way without imposing too much

Comment: for most readers, it would be helpful if you comment & reference the part of the JPA spec, you are referring to. at least give an exact URL to the version of the spec you asking us to comment on.

Comment: Hi all I have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: Any updates on this??

Answer (score 1):

In Java if you define no constructors at all, you'll get a default constructor, which is public and zero-args, i.e. it meets the requirements of the JPA spec.

But if you do define any other constructors, the default constructor is not added automatically, and so the class doesn't meet the JPA requirements. You'd have to add the zero-arg constructor explicitly, next to any other constructors you would want.

As to why the JPA spec needs it: it needs a zero-arg constructor as it wouldn't know what values to pass to the parameters in other constructors.

nb: the stuff you mention about `Class.java` is totally unrelated

Comment: Hi there, I have updated my question, please have a look again.

Comment: `The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. ` This condition is also met if you define no constructors at all (as then the no-arg constructor is implied). Maybe that's where your confusion comes from, the spec doesn't say you must define it explicitly in code. It must "have" it, possibly implied.